# Passing packed array of parameters to an array of module instances in Verilog

Tags: arrays, parameters, verilog, system-verilog

I'm having troubles with passing an array of parameters to multiple instances of the same block.

Here is my tesbench and dut (port list is simplified):

```
module tb_dut_top();

  
  foo_top #(
    .N_DPORT   (3),
    .N_CHAN    ({4'd2, 4'd8, 4'd0}),
    .PORT_TYPE ({2'b11, 2'b11, 2'b00})
  ) i_foo_top (
    .rstb (rstb  ),
    .clk  (clk   )
  );
  
endmodule

module foo_top #(
  parameter                     N_DPORT    = 2,
  parameter [N_DPORT-1:0][ 3:0] N_CHAN     = {N_DPORT{4'd8}},
  parameter [N_DPORT-1:0][ 1:0] PORT_TYPE  = {N_DPORT{2'b11}} 
) (
  input  rstb,
  input  clk
);

  foo_dp_top #(
    .N_CHAN        (N_CHAN[N_DPORT-1:1]          ),
    .PORT_TYPE     (PORT_TYPE[N_DPORT-1:1]       )
  ) i_foo_dp_top[N_DPORT-1:1] (

    .rstb          (rstb                ),
    .clk           (clk                 )
  );
  
endmodule

module foo_dp_top #(
  parameter [ 3:0] N_CHAN = 1,
  parameter [ 1:0] PORT_TYPE = 2'b00
) (
  input rstb,
  input clk
);

endmodule
```

What I want to do is to instantiate (in `foo_top`) N_DPORT * `foo_dp_top` modules (starting from 1, but also starting from 0 did not work) at once passing each of them one item of the arrays N_CHAN and PORT_TYPE.

The instance 1 gets the right value of 8 as N_CHAN, but instance 2 (I want it to get 2 as N_CHAN) keeps getting 8. It seems it propagates the first selected element of the parameter array to all the instances

I'd prefer not to use generate and for loop in order not to add extra hierarchy to the instantiated modules.

Comment: It would be a simpler discovery process of how to do this if you had 2 levels of hierarchy rather than 3, treating the testbench as top.

Comment: I don't think Verilog will iterate over a vector (packed array) with subfields on an array of instances. An array of vectors might iterate over the array of instances. Try creating the parameters with both packed & unpacked dimension. Example [N_DPORT-1:0] N_CHAN [ 3:0] = '{aa,bb,cc,dd,...sixteen values} Note that the default is an assignment pattern '{} rather than a concatenation {};

Comment: @Mikef i tried also with unpacked and unpacked dimension but it gives me the error `expecting datatype compatible with 'packed array' but found 'unpacked array [1:0] of packed array [3:0] of logic' instead`

So it seems it cannot propagate correctly to the instantiated modules individually.

I think i'll get away with the generate loop

Comment: I tried also  There does not seem to be a way to tell Verilog to associate the instances with a particular parameter using this style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with an array of instances because the parameters must be the same for each instance—otherwise it is not really an array. This is exactly what a `generate` construct is for.